# Hide option on condition in Angular Ng-Select

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I am trying to hide `ng-option` elements based on condition...there is an attribute for disabling the option..but is there any attribute to hide them?

```
<ng-select class="w-100" (change)="checkingCategory()" formControlName="category" id="category"
                    name="category" placeholder="-Select Category-" bindValue="value">
                    <ng-option [disabled]="category.key == 'BPF' || category.key == 'ENT'" *ngFor="let category of categoryMap | keyvalue" value={{category.key}}>
                        {{category.key}}-{{category.value}}
                    </ng-option>
                </ng-select>
```

Comment: [hidden] or ngIf doesn't work in ng-select

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two `*` directives on the same element. Try the following

```js
<ng-container 
    *ngFor="let category of categoryMap | keyvalue"
>
   <ng-option *ngIf="someCondition">
   </ng-option>
</ng-container>
```